# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject: Error is in expression '{!UpdateRecord}'

Tags: apex, visualforce

Good day I am having the error shown below:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>   : Error is in expression '{!UpdateRecord}' in component

I am trying to update the lead record with the respective fields.

The record id is being passed on the page url as highlighted below:
https://c.org.visual.force.com/apex/MyPage?id=00Q2XXXX001XXXX

My Visual Force page has a submit button shown below:

```
<apex:commandButton styleClass="submit" value="Submit    Application" action="{!UpdateRecord}"/>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
 public class MyPageController
 {
  public Lead leadDetail 
  {get;set;}
  public Id leadId
  {get;set;}
  //attachment Document name
  public string businessDocName 
  {get;set;}
  //attachment Document body
  public Blob documentBody 
  {get;set;} 
  //attachment ID name
  public string idCardName 
  {get;set;}
  //attachment ID body
  public Blob idCardBody 
  {get;set;} 
   //get the lead id record
   public MyPageController(ApexPages.StandardController ctlr)
     {
      leadId = ctlr.getRecord().Id;     
  }
   //update the fields on the record 
   public PageReference UpdateRecord(){
  Id leadId ;
  //lead custom fields and definitions 
  leadDetail = [SELECT Customer_Name__c, Licence_c, Email_c, Surname_and_First_Name__c, Job_Title__c, Telephone_Number__c FROM Lead WHERE Id  =: leadid];

  PageReference pgRef;
  if((documentBody != null && businessDocName != null)||(idCardBody !=   null && idCardName != null))
  {
      Attachment businessDocument  = new Attachment();
      Attachment idDocument  = new Attachment();
       if(documentBody != null && businessDocName != null)
      {
          businessDocument.Body = documentBody;
          businessDocument.Name = businessDocName;
          businessDocument.ParentId = leadId;
          try
         {
              if(idCardBody != null && idCardName != null)
              { 
                  idDocument.Body = idCardBody;
                  idDocument.Name = idCardName;
                  idDocument.ParentId = leadId;
              }
              insert businessDocument;
              insert idDocument;
          }catch(DMLException e)
          {
              ApexPages.addMessage(new   ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
                  return null;
          }
      }
      pgRef = new PageReference('http://thank.you/');
      pgRef.setRedirect(true);
      return pgRef;
  }   
  return null;
  }    
}
```

What am I missing and how can I resolve it? Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: leadId doesn't have any value thats why you are getting error.... just remove this `Id leadId ;` from `UpdateRecord` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is a miss match between variable naming convention. As updateRecord() method also had leadId variable. You need to remove leadId variable from updateRecord() method.

Comment: @user23 - If that worked can you please mark this answer as the correct answer so the question does not keep appearing as unanswered and so other having a similar question can find answers...

Comment: thanks @Eric sorry the system had asked me to wait a while before marking the answer.